# How to pass data that object in array from ajax to vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Like browing my vue.js code, adrInfo is consist of object in array structure.
I am tryting to get data from ajax to vue via ajax. 
How to recode ajax code?

Ajax

```
$adrInfo = [ 'title' => 'test','zipcode' => 123456, 'adr1'=> 'php street', 'adr2'=> '232'];
return [
   'adrInfo' => $adrInfo,
 ]
```

vue.js

```
 data () {
    return {
        adrInfo: [{
            title: '', zipcode: '', adr1: '', adr2: ''
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backend have to return an HTTP response with JSON body that's all. With VueJS you can use [Axios](https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/) for exemple, or [Vue-Resources](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) to call your API and fetch the response.